# Real-Time Updates: Certificate verify failed

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate, real-time-updates

I am currently trying to set up Real-Time Updates to my site through the facebook app interface. When I attempt to test the callback to the callback url of https://messageall.com/facebook/callback/ I am getting an error message of:

```
Callback verification failed: 
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

However from what I can tell the certificate key chain is working fine and verifies when I test via http://www.digicert.com/help/

What could the facebook servers think is wrong with my CA?

Comment: The check at https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/ reports some issues, but I can’t tell you if those upset Facebook.

Comment: OK, the error message you’re getting speaks of `SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE` that’s failing, but according to the checker I linked your domain does not support SSL3 – so maybe that’s the issue.

Comment: That's a lot better checker, I'll use that from now on, I've fixed a few of the issues that it raised and changed the ciphers that the server uses, and now it includes SSLv3 which that check is showing working. But facebook is still returning that error.